# Persistent Bottomsheet Dialog

Tags: kotlin, android-viewbinding, android-bottomsheetdialog

I have a fragment that contains a Persistent bottom sheet dialog, but i already use viewbinding and databinding in my project, so when i declare bottom sheet behavior, when i declare

```
BottomSheetBehavior.from(binding.bottom_sheet)
```

It said that Unresolved reference: bottom_sheet

. Is it inappropriate to use persistent bottom sheet with view binding and databinding?

this is my bottom_sheet.xml

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bottom_round_corner"
    app:behavior_hideable="true"
    app:behavior_peekHeight="56dp"
    app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior">
```

and this is my fragment that contains bottom sheet

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout 

xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".testscreen.MainFragment">
     <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    ...
     </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/fragment_bottom_sheet"/>

    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

i tried to specify the ID of bottom sheet in fragment containing it , but it's not work at all

```
<include layout="@layout/fragment_bottom_sheet" android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"/>
```